# How do I declare a constructor for an 'object' class type in Scala? I.e., a one time operation for the singleton

Tags: scala

I know that objects are treated pretty much like singletons in scala.  However, I have been unable to find an elegant way to specify default behavior on initial instantiation. I can accomplish this by just putting code into the body of the object declaration but this seems overly hacky.  Using an apply doesn't really work because it can be called multiple times and doesn't really make sense for this use case.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Classes and objects both run the code in their body upon instantiation, by design.  Why is this "hacky"?  It's how the language is supposed to work.  If you like extra braces, you can always use them (and they'll keep local variables from being preserved and world-viewable).

```
object Initialized {
  // Initalization block
  {
    val someStrings = List("A","Be","Sea")
    someStrings.filter(_.contains('e')).foreach(s => println("Contains e: " + s))
  }

  def doSomething { println("I was initialized before you saw this.") }
}

scala> Initialized.doSomething
Contains e: Be
Contains e: Sea
I was initialized before you saw this.

scala> Initialized.someStrings
<console>:9: error: value someStrings is not a member of object Initialized
       Initialized.someStrings
```

Comment: You know I guess I overthought it and really just wanted a standard way to do it.  This is exactly what I tried but I didn't want to use code just because it happened to work :) Thanks!

Comment: I agree with the original poster that putting code into the body of the class as a constructor looks ugly - more like a script than a class.  The answer given here is the same way I do it, also because it mimics the behavior of the Java instance initializer (not constructor).  It's cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 19):

Rex has it right, I just wanted to point out a pattern I use a lot, that saves you from having to use vars, while avoiding namespace pollution by intermediate values.

```
object Foo {
  val somethingFooNeeds = {
    val intermediate = expensiveCalculation
    val something = transform(intermediate)
    something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

If it makes you feel better, you can create some class with protected constructor and `object` will create singleton of this class:

```
sealed class MyClass protected (val a: String, b: Int) {
  def doStuff = a + b
}

object MyObject extends MyClass("Hello", b = 1)
```

Also notice, that `sealed` stops other classes and objects to extend `MyClass` and `protected` will not allow creation of other `MyClass` instances.

But I personally don't see any problems with some code in the body of the object. You can also create some method like `init` and just call it:

```
object MyObject {
  init()

  def init() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: The init method is an excellent idea.  I only worry about the potential for it to be called from within the class at some point.  Glad to hear the first block method is standard. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The body of object and class declarations IS the default constructor and any code placed in there will be executed upon first reference, so that is exactly the way to do it.