# How to use singelton (object) in Scala with parameters?

Tags: scala

I want to build a role functionality for my application. So, I thought `object` would come in handy because I need a Singelton of all different roles.

Therefore, I have the following code:

```
trait Role {
  def id: UUID

  def name: String
}

object Admin extends Role {
  val id = UUID.randomUUID()
  val name = "admin"
}


object Pro extends Role {
  val id = UUID.randomUUID()
  val name = "pro"
}
```

However, after I persisted these roles in my database and restarted the application, I noticed that the `id` of the roles changed, meaning it's not the same role as I persisted them when I started the application in the first place. So, I would need to set the `id` if a role with the same name has already been stored in the database and set it to the Singelton object. I thought that I could use parameters to initialize the `Admin` and `Pro` object, but apparently this does not work.

How can this be done?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200247/how-do-i-declare-a-constructor-for-an-object-class-type-in-scala-i-e-a-one

Comment: How are you persisting our objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the below code:

```
object Admin extends Role {
  val id = getPersistedIDFromDatabase(name).getOrElse { 
    pesistID(name, UUID.randomUUID())
  }
  val name = "admin"
}

// getThePersistedIDFromDatabase => executes the `select` SQL query and returns an Optional ID, i.e., Some(id) if the admin already exists; Otherwise None.
```

Whenever you restart your application, its memory is wiped out. So it has no way to know about your previous ID.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is difficult to discuss the problem by only seeing this code, without knowing how you try to do the database persistence part.

Following your code, the id is initialised by calling randomUUID, so surely you get a new one with each start. System works as designed.

Second, I am not sure if we would agree about what a singleton is and what is the semantic of the two 'objects'.

To me it looks as if you indeed would like to have two different instances of the type Role, instead of one singleton type Admin and one different singleton type Pro, because the two differ only in the attributed values, not in structure.

A singleton object is already an object, indeed the sole object of its type. So the notion of setting its values from outside during some sort of construction, like you would do with classes during instantiation,  is not really applicable here.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will change my software design now by removing the objects and just create a class `Role`. Do you agree that this is better?

Comment: Well, it depends. I don't know your application design. But either you want to explicitly design your code around the fixed named singleton objects, then I don't see the need to persist anything in DB, or you design a more generic/dynamic role concept, where persisted role instances form values, then I don't see the singleton pattern. (Just my humble opinion)